# FileTransfer to WCF Service receiving 405

Tags: wcf, rest, cordova

I'm working on a mobile app using PhoneGap, and one of the features involves uploading an image to a web service for processing. I've written a WCF service that's hosted in IIS to accept the image, with a contract that looks like the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IImages
{
    [OperationContract(Name="UploadImage")]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?file_key={fileKey}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    ImageResource UploadImage(string fileKey, Stream imageStream);
}
```

The configuration section in my web.config looks like:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="Services.Images" relativeAddress="images.svc" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior" name="Services.Images">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PublicStreamBinding" contract="Services.Contracts.IImages" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PublicStreamBinding"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="30" maxConcurrentInstances="30" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I attempt to upload a file to the endpoint, using PhoneGap's FileTransfer class, the response returned from the service is a 405 Method Not Allowed. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** The function in my mobile app that's uploading the file is below. This code previous worked fine when pointed to an older ASMX service.

```
    ns.UploadImage = function(){
        //alert(ns.Dictionary['LocalImagePath']);

        var uri = ns.Dictionary['LocalImagePath'];

        try {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();

            options.fileKey = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + ".jpeg";
            options.fileName = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + ".jpeg";
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

            var ft = new FileTransfer();

            ft.upload(uri, GetServerUrl()+"images.svc?file_key="+options.fileKey, ns.UploadImageSuccess, ns.UploadImageError, options);

        } catch (e) {
            ns.UploadImageError(e);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to upload the file, too?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the post with the function that uploads the file to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured this out. Apparently, when the method is hosted at the root like this, if you don't follow the name of the service in the uri with '/', the request won't get routed correctly. So, in the function that uploads the file, I changed the ft.upload line to the following:

```
ft.upload(uri, GetServerUrl()+"images.svc/?file_key="+options.fileKey, ns.UploadImageSuccess, ns.UploadImageError, options);
```

Which worked.

Comment: What is the ImageResource class that you are using?